# Why isn't Python 3.4 pip install working on windows?

Tags: python, windows, gitlab-ci

I have Python 3.4 installed on a gitlab windows runner. I want to create a virtual environment, and inside, install http.client.
This is the gitlab-ci.yml script:

```
- py -3.4 -m venv venv/vanguard_py3.4 
- ./venv/vanguard_py3.4/Scripts/python -m pip install -U pip
- ./venv/vanguard_py3.4/Scripts/pip3 install http.client
```

When i run this, during the install pip command, i get a whole bunch of errors like this one:

*** Error compiling 'D:\builds\000\9ZdLTcFG\0\sristea\qos-sdk\venv\vanguard_py3.4\build\pip\pip\_internal\build_env.py'...
File "D:\builds\000\9ZdLTcFG\0\sristea\qos-sdk\venv\vanguard_py3.4\build\pip\pip_internal\build_env.py", line 81
self._bin_dirs: List[str] = []
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Can't find anything on the internet that helps, and i don't really work with python and i don't know how to fix it myself. Has anyone encountered this problem or know how to solve it?

Comment: `self._bin_dirs: List[str] = []` is a type hint. Type hints were added in 3.5

Comment: @Passerby Ok, but i try to install pip using python3.4 why does it use type hints? Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: We typically try to avoid upgrading pip in CI, containers, etc. Instead, if you need a newer version than what comes with the version of Python, pin pip (i.e. `.../python -m pip install pip==22.3.1`). This makes our CI and CD processes much more reliable